# string match and lower case characters in lua

Tags: lua

I need help with lower case character and string match...

items.xml

```
    <item id="2432" article="a" name="fire axe">
    <attribute key="description" value="The blade is a magic flame." />
    <attribute key="weight" value="4000" />
    <attribute key="defense" value="16" />
    <attribute key="attack" value="38" />
    <attribute key="elementFire" value="11" />
    <attribute key="weaponType" value="axe" />
    <attribute key="extradef" value="1" />
</item>
<item id="2493" article="a" name="Demon Helmet">
    <attribute key="description" value="You hear an evil whispering from the inside." />
    <attribute key="weight" value="2950" />
    <attribute key="armor" value="10" />
    <attribute key="slotType" value="head" />
</item>
```

Now, it's is my function:

```
function seachItem(name) 
local items = io.open("data/items/items.xml", "r"):read("*all")
local get = items:match('name="' .. name ..'"')
if get == nil or get == "" then
    return false
end
return true
end
```

but only works with lowercase items, example of fire axe.

the function cannot find the "Demon helmet" with a lowercase letter, is there any way to change the match function so that it already comes with the lowercase letter?

exemple:

```
local var = "demon helmet" -- lower case
  if seachItem(var) then
      print("Ok")
 end
```

Comment: `local get = items:lower():match('name="' .. name:lower() ..'"')`

Comment: works!! Thanks Egor Skriptunoff!! U are a god!!